# How to show the menu of UIButton().menu only when long pressed in iOS?

Tags: ios

By setting UIButton().menu, a menu can be shown when tapped.

And a menu is shown when long pressed, too.

I want to execute some another action (for example, change text) when tapped, and show a menu when long pressed.

How to show a menu only when long pressed, like Safari's `show tabs button` on the right bottom of the screen?

In Safari, tabs are shown when `show tabs button` is tapped, and a menu is shown when `show tabs button` is long pressed.

Comment: You need to set showsMenuAsPrimaryAction to false

Comment: @Vikassaini I didn't know that long press only is default. Setting showsMenuAsPrimaryAction to false worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = false
```